# LINQ casting during enumeration

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary, casting

I have a `List<string>`

```
List<string> students;
students.Add("Rob");
students.Add("Schulz");
```

and a `Dictionary<string,string>`

```
Dictionary<string, string> classes= new Dictionary<string, string>();
classes.Add("Rob", "Chemistry");  
classes.Add("Bob", "Math"); 
classes.Add("Holly", "Physics"); 
classes.Add("Schulz", "Botany");
```

My objective now is to get a List with the values - `Chemistry` and `Botany` - for which I am using this

```
var filteredList = students.Where(k => classes.ContainsKey(k))
                                         .Select(k => new { tag = students[k] });
```

While trying to enumerate the values - I am able to obtain - `tag=Chemistry` & `tag=Botany`...while I want just `Chemistry` and `Botany`.

What is the appropriate casting to be applied? Is there a better way to get to these values?

Comment: What you want is not really clear. Could you explain exactly what you expect ? `{ "Chemistry", "Botany" }` or something else ?

Comment: Have you tried just returning students[k] rather than a new anonymous type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have to write:

```
var filteredList = students.Where(student => classes.ContainsKey(student));
```

Here, `student` is a `string`, since `students` is a `List<string>`, so you only have to apply [Where()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx). The result will be an `IEnumerable<string>`.

You can apply [ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) if you want to exhaust the enumerable into another `List<string>`:

```
var filteredList = students.Where(student => classes.ContainsKey(student)).ToList();
```

If you want a list of classes (it's not clear from the code in your question), then you have to apply [Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891) to project classes from students:

```
var filteredList = students.Where(student => classes.ContainsKey(student))
                           .Select(student => classes[student]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var filteredList = students.Where(k => classes.ContainsKey(k))
                                     .Select(k => students[k]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filteredList = students.Where(k => classes.ContainsKey(k))
                                         .Select(k => students[k]);
```