# LINQ Equivalent query

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary, linq-to-objects

I have a

```
 List<string>     

List<string> students; 
students.Add("123Rob"); 
students.Add("234Schulz");
```

and a

```
Dictionary<string,string> 

Dictionary<string, string> courses = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 
courses .Add("Rob", "Chemistry");   
courses .Add("Bob", "Math");  
courses .Add("Holly", "Physics"); 
courses .Add("Schulz", "Botany");
```

My objective now is to get a List with the values - `{Chemistry,Botany}` .

In other words, I am trying to get the LINQ equivalent of

```
select value from [courses]
where [courses].key in 
(
select [courses].key from courses,students where [students].id LIKE '%courses.key%'
)
```

How should the LINQ query be framed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ casting during enumeration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146296/linq-casting-during-enumeration)

Comment: @L.B you're wrong ..this is not a duplicate,please remove dv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the correct answer:

```
var values = from c in courses
             where students.Any(s => s.IndexOf(c.Key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
             select c.Value;
```

Tested on my machine. 
Hope this can help.

Comment: You're better off using `s.IndexOf(c.Key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0` - using ToLower() isn't ideal for doing a case insensitive comparison.